# Why aren't destructors called when an uncaught exception is throw in C++ during array creation?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, destructor

```
class XX
{
public:
    static unsigned s_cnt;
    XX()
    {
        ++ s_cnt;
        std::cout << "C XX " << s_cnt << "\n";

        if ( s_cnt > 2 )
            throw std::exception();
    }

    //private:
    ~XX()
    {
        std::cout << "~ XX\n";
    }
};
unsigned XX::s_cnt = 0;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        XX *xx = new XX[10];
    } catch ( ... )
    {
        std::cout << "Exc\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C XX 1
C XX 2
C XX 3
~ XX
~ XX
Exc
```

But when i remove try-catch, i see:

```
C XX 1
C XX 2
C XX 3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
  what():  std::exception
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

Why does C++ call the destructors in first case but not in second?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you don't catch an exception (i.e. it becomes an uncaught exception and terminates your program), C++ doesn't give you any guarantees that destructors actually get called.

This gives the compilers leeway in how to implement exception handling. For example, GCC first searches for a handler. If it can't find one, it aborts immediately, preserving the full stack information for debugging. If it does find one, it actually unwinds the stack, destroying objects, until it arrives at the handler. That's why you don't see output: the program aborts before destroying any objects.

Comment: You might add that the reason for this is so that you don't loose state information in the core dump.

Answer (score 3):

When you throw an exception from a constructor, the standard treat the object as *not constructed*. You don't destroy something that does not exists, don't you?

In fact, even this simple example doesn't work as you suggest:

```
struct A {
    A() {throw std::exception();}
    ~A() {std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

This terminates with an uncaught exception, but does not print "A::~A()".

If you think about it, it's the only possible way to give a semantic to it.

For example, we can use our type A as a member object of a class B:

```
struct B {
    B() : m_a(),m_p(new int) {}
    ~B() {delete m_p;}

    A m_a;
    int * m_p;
};
```

Obviously `B::B()` throws immediately (and doesn't even initialize `m_p`). If an hypothetical C++ standard mandates to calls `B::~B()` in this case, the destructor has no possible way to know if `m_p` has been initialized or not.

In other words, throwing an exception from a constructor *means that the object never existed and its lifetime never began*. This [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) is pretty clear about it.

Bonus: what happens if in the definition of `B` we swap the order of `m_a` and `m_p` ?
Then you have a memory leak. That's why exists a particular syntax to catch exception during the initialization of member objects.

Comment: new XX[10] constructs the objects one by one. The first 2 objects are constructed without any problem. Then it attempts to construct the 3rd and fails. Then it calls the destructor for XX[1] and XX[0], but NOT XX[2]. In fact you have only 2 `~XX` lines in your output, not 3.

Comment: I was referring to the second case, where the `try` block has been removed and no destructors are called, despite objects being constructed. You aren't addressing that part of the question.

Comment: Well I missed the edit where you changed the question title, my bad. The second part is addressed by @Sebastian Redl answer. But it has nothing to do with the fact that you are working with arrays.

Comment: You've answered a quection 'why not yet constructed objects are not deleted', but this is not the subject of my question :)

Comment: @sbabbi that means we have to wrap every constructor that calls `new` in a try, catch block ? because in that case if you do for example `std::vector< int > a(42);` and then `A a;` it will create a leak

Comment: @Fayeure If you use raw new/delete, yes. With `make_unique` there is no need to. There are no leaks in the example. Member objects of `A` are destroyed as needed. After the constructor throws, member object that have been initialized will be destroyed. Just the destructor of  `A` will not be called.